# SSIS Custom component not showing up in toolbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to create a "hello world" custom dataflow transform.

My setup is:
Visual Studio 2019 16.4.2
SQL Server data tools 16.0.61912.09160
My local machine is running Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)

After trying for hours to get my dll to register as a custom dataflow component I created an empty bare-bones custom component that does not do anything making sure that:

- Referenced the *DTS* assemblies from the v.40_*** folders   example: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll
- The referenced *DTS* asseblies all had "specific version" set to false
- Used a strong name for the assembly

With this I:

- Registered it in the GAC
- Copied the dll to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\PipelineComponents
- Restarted Visual Studio

But still no custom compent in the toolbox.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Reference material on [Custom Data Flow Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/data-flow/creating-a-custom-data-flow-component?view=sql-server-ver15) It's been nearly a decade since I built my last component but it seems like you have the correct steps down

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SSIS 2014, to support multi-targeting feature of SSDT, custom component developers are required to set an “alias” for each extension. The mapping between the alias and the extension is called “extension mapping”. In %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\{version}\DTS\UpgradeMappings folder, you can find an “extension extension.xml” file, which contains all extension mapping for all extensions in the product. You also need to add a new extension map file for your extensions. Below is an example of the extension mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Extensions xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts/Extensions.xsd">
<PipelineComponents>
<PipelineComponent Identifier="<your component name from DisplayName property>" Model=".NET">
<CreationName>'your component namespace and class name', 'component assembly name', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...</CreationName>
</PipelineComponent>
</PipelineComponents>
</Extensions>
```

Sample from a real project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Extensions xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts/Extensions.xsd">
  <PipelineComponents>
    <PipelineComponent Identifier="SrcSys Data" Model=".NET">
      <CreationName>MyCompany.SrcSys.SrcSysRead, MyCompany.SrcSys.Src.2016, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d934c2f83a6e8e9a</CreationName>
      <TypeConverter name="Request Type">MyCompany.SrcSys.Adapt_Const+RequestType, MyCompany.SrcSys.Src.2016, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d934c2f83a6e8e9a</TypeConverter>
    </PipelineComponent>
  </PipelineComponents>
</Extensions>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am really impressed that you managed to dig this up. It almost seems like MS is actively trying to discourage development of custom components with all the hoops you have to jump through to make it work. I added my component to the extensions.xml file like you outlined. It still does not work. Do I need an upgrade mapping file if I only target one sql server version (2019)?

Comment: @PeterK If you target your project to SSIS 2019, you have to put your `extensions.xml` file to %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\UpgradeMappings. Added file as a sample from project. Typeconverner node only needed if you added property of custom type into your custom component.